# Add item to specific position otherwise push zero in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have empty array in that I want to add specific items at specific position which are coming from web api and want to add zero(0) to remaining positions dynamically using javscript. 
Here is my Code :-

```
let arraydata = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
arraydata.splice(5, 0, 4)
document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = arraydata;
```

[My Code](https://jsfiddle.net/myj1e0zu/)

Right now I have added zero manually,I want to add 0 upto 12 index and want to add 4 at 5th position synamicaaly.

Comment: what is actually your problem, to fill the array, the splicing part, or the changing length with splicing?

Comment: I have 12 index array in which I am getting values for different positions that I have to insert dynamically otherwise remaining indexes will be zero that's why I want this functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map`:

```js
let arraydata = Array(12).fill();
arraydata.splice(5, 0, 4);
arraydata = arraydata.map(e => e ? e : 0);
console.log(arraydata);
```

You can also add different values - just place them inside the `fill`:

```js
let arraydata = Array(12).fill("Things");
arraydata.splice(5, 0, 4);
arraydata = arraydata.map(e => e ? e : 0);
console.log(arraydata);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `fill()` array with `0`

```js
let arraydata = Array(12).fill(0)
arraydata.splice(5, 0, 4)
console.log(arraydata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
let array = new Array(12).fill(0);
array.splice(5,0,4);
console.log(array);
```

If you want to update an index rather than adding a new value at particular index, rather than splice, you should simply do `array[5] = 4`

Answer (score 1):

You can build a generic function like this

```js
let desiredArr = (length, value, from, to)=>{
  let arr = new Array(length).fill(0)
  arr.splice(value, from, to)
  return arr
}

console.log(desiredArr(12, 5, 0 ,4))
```

If there's always only one index you want to update than you can simply do this

```js
let arr = new Array(12).fill(0)
arr[5] = 4

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign the value at the wanted index without splicing, which increases the length of the array.

```js
let arraydata = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
arraydata[5] = 4;

console.log(...arraydata);
```

If you like to keep the splicing, you could keep the length by assigning the wwanted length.

```js
let arraydata = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
arraydata.splice(5, 0, 4);
arraydata.length = 12;

console.log(...arraydata);
```